# Changing a login email done through Stack Overflow instead of Stack Exchange, and in two different places

Tags: discussion, support, login, user-accounts, email

First I should clarify that I don't ask a question like "How do change a Stack Exchange login email?" and there are already such few (duplicated) questions.

I ask the following question to better understand how the Stack Exchange network is structured and if any major change is planned, as I believe it will be helpful for others and for myself:

**Why does changing a login email done through Stack Overflow instead through Stack Exchange?**

Another question I have that I think both clarifies the need of the first question and derives from it (but maybe best to be asked in a separate session) is:

**Why should users change their emails in two places:**
**1)** https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/`USER_ACCOUNT_NMUMBER`
**2)** https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/`USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER`
**Instead in just one?**

<sub>I humbly assume changing login email through Stack Exchange and in one place instead of two, would reduce system complexity and be more convenient and accessible for users.</sub>

### Update per answer by animuson

I didn't know setting email**s** could be done from any site in the network besides *StackOverflow* and excluding *Meta StackExchange*; I was used to do so from StackOverflow and assumed it is possible only there as a legacy.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339996/problem-with-replacing-email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by Stack Overflow instead of Stack Exchange. You can make these same profile changes on any site on the entire network where you have a profile, except on stackexchange.com directly which is a read-only network stub:
Thus, you cannot make changes of any kind there and we will never be expanding what you are allowed to do there (if anything, it will reduce further).

That aside, you are required to change your email in two places because those emails do entirely different things. We allow you to have an unlimited number of credentials tied to your account, tied to any number of different email addresses:

- Adding a new email in your logins says you want to be able to login with that email. This is a common setup for people who want both their work and personal emails attached to the same account, for convenience purposes.
- Changing your email in the email settings, controls where you want notifications to be sent to, then have a preference as to which email they'd like notifications sent.

Comment: Hello; I edited the question to answer the "wondering" I grasped from the first sentence of the answer; I suggested an edit accordingly; one approved and one rejected so I invite you to review it. Thanks anyway, for your time and answer.