# New verified email isn't recognized properly

Tags: feature-request, support, login, user-accounts, email

I have changed my Stack Exchange login email address to a new email address in the following two configuration pages and verified the new email from its inbox.

**1)** https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/`USER_ACCOUNT_NMUMBER`
**2)** https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/`USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER`

In the first configuration page, everything seems alright (the new email appears as the only one for notifications about all Stack Exchange communities I have joined);
But, when I navigate to the second configuration page,
I get this pattern:

[image]

At least now, I do indeed want to keep the old email address as an additional valid login credential,
But I don't understand why does the new email appears under the *Other* part of page, instead under the *Stack Exchange* part of page and on top of the old email address.

How could one move a new verified email address to be under the *Stack Exchange* part of page and also to be on top of the old email address, so that nothing will appear under the *Other* part of page?

<sub>P.S: I found no session on this</sub>

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339749/changing-a-login-email-done-through-stack-overflow-instead-of-stack-exchange-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that with time, both email addresses were rearranged under *Stack Exchange* part of page.

- I don't know how much time passed since the day of change and the actual rearrangement though;
  I would assume it's a matter of one week - a mod with deeper knowledge of the system is welcome to edit this answer with the exact time frame.

Anyway, **I could now remove the old email** and it seemed to me that finally this saga of email change came to its end.