# I just registered to Area 51 and it sent a confirmation email to my old (already-changed) email address

Tags: bug, area-51, user-accounts, email, email-notification

I just registered to Area 51 and it sent a confirmation email to my old (already-changed) email address; here is a screenshot to indicate this:

[image]

### Well,

This problem seems to be related to another strange problem I already reported here in Meta SE:

[New verified email isn't recognized properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339996/new-verified-email-isnt-recognized-properly)

The following link appears in the screenshot above:

> If this email address is incorrect, please update your user profile

But I already did so as described in my question and answer in the above linked session.

### Update

I didn't confirm the email in the old email box (which I can still access), instead, I clicked on the linked and surprisingly saw my old email which I was sure that was deleted from all StackExchange systems already; I changed it to my new email already updated in Stackoverflow (and via it, allegedly all over the network) and confirmed my Area51 account from my new email only.

I can only hope, I won't have any problem in the future !

Comment: It's the same issue as [A user's originally registered email address is retained in the system even after they've changed it on all sites (privacy risk)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-originally-registered-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-afte). Basically, your original email address is retained in the system in a legacy field that is not changed when you update your email on a main site, and Area 51 (being that it runs on a very old fork of the SE engine) uses that old legacy field.

Comment: TL;DR - sorry ; I assume the answerer means to say that in first registration to some network website (say, stackoverflow) --- the email is cloned to some other site for possible future registration; if so, I am dissapointed because I find it problematic.

Comment: I know re read your comment after you updated it --- seems I was quite close or quite accurate. bummer. Thanks,